# T-SQL XML: How do I get my results in the format listed below?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

This is my first time here. I need to get my XML formatted in the following format:

```
<Summary Year="2018" QtrNum="1" WeekNum="4" Date="1/22/2018" Code="101">
```

Once I get it to this format, then I need this XML generated for each row of my table. Here is a screenshot of the expected result set.

[Expected Result Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7sYy.jpg)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add sample data.... Best was to add a MCVE (DML and DDL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is rather unclear, my magig crystal ball tells me, that you might be looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE @someTable TABLE(SomeDate DATE, SomeQrt INT, SomeWeek INT, SomeCode INT);
INSERT INTO @someTable VALUES('20180122',1,4,101);

DECLARE @SomeRelatedTable TABLE(SomeText VARCHAR(100),SomeCode INT);
INSERT INTO @SomeRelatedTable VALUES('Row 1',101)
                            ,('Row 2',101)
                            ,('Other code',999);

SELECT YEAR(t.SomeDate) AS [@Year]
      ,t.SomeQrt AS [@QrtNum]
      ,t.SomeWeek AS [@WeekNum]
      ,t.SomeDate AS [@Date]
      ,t.SomeCode AS [@Code]
      ,(
        SELECT SomeText AS [@InnerText]
        FROM @SomeRelatedTable rt
        WHERE rt.SomeCode=t.SomeCode
        FOR XML PATH('InnerNode'),TYPE
       )
FROM @someTable t           
FOR XML PATH('Summary');
```

The result

```
<Summary Year="2018" QrtNum="1" WeekNum="4" Date="2018-01-22" Code="101">
  <InnerNode InnerText="Row 1" />
  <InnerNode InnerText="Row 2" />
</Summary>
```

Some Explanation

`FOR XML PATH` allows full control over the XML generation through the column's alias and `PATH` / `ROOT` extension.

The related (inner) nodes are created with a correlated sub-query.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your feedback. This helps me but I'm still short on what I need. So I don't need the results of the XML grouped by location but rather the XML itself grouped by location. So When the final query is ran instead of receiving just one XML result. I would like to receive an XML result per location. Does this make sense?

Comment: @EricHathcock *Does this make sense?* Nope, not for me... Try to add sample data and expected outcome. See the way I declared a mockup scenario, copy and paste this, adjust it to your needs and show what you want to get. Use the edit option of your question to re-work your question. You might place a comment here after you are done in order to give me an alert.

Comment: Again, this is my first time here so I apologize for my inexperience. I was able to resolve my issue. i'll update the question and answer section now.

Comment: @EricHathcock Welcome on SO, Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem. Look at the scenario below.

```
drop table #test
create table #test(id int identity(1,1),locationcode varchar(6),businessdate date, quarternum int, weeknum int)

insert into #test(locationcode,businessdate, quarternum, weeknum)
values('000001',GETDATE(),2,2),
('000001',GETDATE(),2,2),
('000002',GETDATE(),2,2),
('000003',GETDATE(),2,2),
('000004',GETDATE(),2,2),
('000005',GETDATE(),2,2),
('000006',GETDATE(),2,2),
('000007',GETDATE(),2,2)

SELECT 
    (SELECT YEAR(b.businessdate) AS '@Year',b.QuarterNum AS '@QtrNum',b.WeekNum AS '@WeekNum',FORMAT(b.BusinessDate,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS '@Date'
                ,b.LocationCode  AS '@Code' 
     FROM #test c where b.id = c.id FOR XML PATH('DailySummary'),TYPE) AS Row
FROM #test b
```